# Swift, Calculating and inserting data into a text field

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an app that prorates rent for class, but whenever I plugin all of the data and press the calculate button, it just show the word "inf" in the text box.

the code is as follows:

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {




@IBAction func tapIt(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    monthlyRent.resignFirstResponder()
    moveInMonth.resignFirstResponder()
    moveInDay.resignFirstResponder()
    moveInYear.resignFirstResponder()
    billOn.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}

var daysInMonth : Int = Int()
var temp : Int = Int()
var daysLivingThere : Int = Int()
var rentPerDay : Double = Double()
var billingDays2 : Int = Int()
var proratedRent : Double = Double()
var addIn = 1
var passingData : String = String()
var dollar = "$"

@IBOutlet var monthlyRent: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var moveInMonth: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var moveInDay: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var moveInYear: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var billOn: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var fieldA: UITextField!


@IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {


    let rentMonthly : Double? = Double(monthlyRent.text!)
    let dayMoveIn : Int? = Int(moveInDay.text!)
    let billingDays : Int? = Int(billOn.text!)
    let monthDays : Double? = Double(daysInMonth)


    switch moveInMonth
    {
    case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12:
        daysInMonth = 31
    case 4, 6, 9, 11:
        daysInMonth = 30
    case 2:
        daysInMonth = 28
    default:
        break
    }


    billingDays2 = billingDays! - addIn
    temp = daysInMonth - dayMoveIn!
    daysLivingThere = temp + billingDays2

    rentPerDay = rentMonthly! / monthDays!
    let a : Double? = Double(daysLivingThere)
    proratedRent = rentPerDay + a!

    let b : String? = String(proratedRent)
    fieldA.text = dollar + b!


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "btnSubmitSegue") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController;
        svc.dataPassed = fieldA.text!
    }
}
```

}

All of the code is located inside of a button. I want to transfer the data from the text box to a secondary view controller and desperately need the text box to work.

Comment: I took a guess below, but it would help to have all of the relevant source.  In this case, we know we're missing the declaration of `daysInMonth`

Comment: On a side note, you should never use `Double` to store currency values due to floating point rounding errors. Either use `Int` and store the total number of cents, or use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: I'll update to show everything within the class.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `monthDays` is set before `daysInMonth`, which it depends on, move the `let monthDays :...` line to after the `moveInMonth` switch.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what David Berry said, I ran this in a playground and it failed to compile because "error: constant 'daysInMonth' used before being initialized". Make sure to initialize these values and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

David is right:

change this:

```
let rentMonthly : Double? = Double(monthlyRent.text!)
let dayMoveIn : Int? = Int(moveInDay.text!)
let billingDays : Int? = Int(billOn.text!)
let monthDays : Double? = Double(daysInMonth)


switch moveInMonth
{
case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12:
    daysInMonth = 31
case 4, 6, 9, 11:
    daysInMonth = 30
case 2:
    daysInMonth = 28
default:
    break
}
```

to this:

```
let rentMonthly : Double? = Double(monthlyRent.text!)
let dayMoveIn : Int? = Int(moveInDay.text!)
let billingDays : Int? = Int(billOn.text!)


switch moveInMonth
{
case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12:
    daysInMonth = 31
case 4, 6, 9, 11:
    daysInMonth = 30
case 2:
    daysInMonth = 28
default:
    break
}

let monthDays : Double? = Double(daysInMonth)
```

Comment: I tried it and it still showed "inf" in the text box